# Connecting with MS Access Data source from java code

Tags: java, jdbc, odbc

I have created a `.mdb` file using MS Access. I have created a `User DSN` in windows. now i want to connect to this data source using java code ? how can i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emm... As I can remember, you have to create DataSource (see image)

[image]

... then use [jdbc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbt582h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to access it; [Here](http://www.easysoft.com/applications/microsoft-access/jdbc-odbc.html) is a good example of how to do this;

**EDIT** : 
In case of remote datasource request you may use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html) instructions which describe how to create the **bridge**;

put attention at this snippets :

```
Class.forName(sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver) ;

       // setup the properties 
       java.util.Properties prop = new java.util.Properties();
       prop.put("charSet", "Big5");
       prop.put("user", username);
       prop.put("password", password);

       // Connect to the database
       con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, prop);
```

and this one :

```
...
    sun.jdbc.odbc.ee.DataSource ds = new sun.jdbc.odbc.ee.DataSource();

                // Provide user credentials and database name

                ds.setUser("scott");
                ds.setPassword("tiger");
                ds.setDatabaseName("dsn1");
                ds.setCharSet("..."); // optional property
                ds.setLoginTimeout(100); // optional property

                // Establish initial context and bind to the datasource target

                InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
                ic.bind("jdbc/OdbcDB1",ds);
...
```

...which is showing of how to set datasource name in case of any url

---

Please do comment if you have more details

Good luck :)

Comment: Many thanks - yeah. the access database is on another machine. what is the connection string to connect remotely??

Comment: the remote machine or local machine have difference in IPs; For example local has 127.0.0.1 (or DNS like a "myserver") and remote may have any IP or any DNS:) So do play with jdbc "servername" argument ; The servername url something like this http://127.0.0.1:8031 for local or http://xxx.xxx.x.x:8031 for a remote one...

Comment: what will be the Complete url of connection string? is it jdbc:odbc:192.xxx.xxx.xxx:8031:myDS ??